# unable to configure data logging system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, directory, package, fltk

I am using a virtual machine where Lubuntu is installed and my host is windows7. I am trying to generate make files through

> "./configure --prefix=${PREFIX}" but it is saying that "configure:
>   error: fltk-config not found. Please use --with-fltk-dir"

By using synaptic manager I tried installing some packages related which did not help.

Comment: I tried installing now with "$ sudo apt install fltk1.3-dev". which now is giving me a new error saying that "checking FFTW3... configure: error: FFTW3 not installed in /usr/local or /usr!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sudo apt install fltk1.3-dev 
and then in synaptic manager search for FFTW3 and install the packages available with name FFTW3. Then its done